# How to get my object transparent, texture not?

Tags: texturing

I made a plane with a texture on it. The texture has multiple places where it should be transparent. How can I make it that the object is transparent and the texture not?
Thanks,
Jonas

Comment: If the object is transparent then you cannot see the texture anyway. Are you using Cycles?

Comment: using blender render